# Find object in list in go template language

Tags: go-templates

I have the following structure:

```
obj:
  - name: "listitem1"
    value: "value1"
  - name: "listitem2"
    value: "value2"
  - name: "listitem3"
    value: "value3"
```

I'd like to do a check if `obj` contains an item with `name = listitem2` and get its value. Can I do that with some clever function or do I have to iterate with `range` and `if`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value cannot be retrieved through the built-in functions. However, one could check if a specific `key=value` pair is present with the following syntax:

```
{{- if has (dict "name" "listitem1" "value" "value1") .Values.my.custom.value.map }}
```

Comment: what if I don't know the value and wont to select just by name?